# jquery adding attr values

Tags: jquery, scroll, attr

I have at the bottom in the else statement subtracting, which works fine, but the if statement is not correctly adding values.  How the script works, when the user scrolls it moves as fast as speed-racers value tells it to move, speed-racer subtracts from racer-offset, when racer-offset is 0, it stops any further movement, then when the user scrolls back the opposite direction, it should add the value of speed-racer back to racer-offset till it reaches leftMovements value, in which it will stop.  It subtracts correctly, but when it is suppose to add values back is where the problem begins. In the image below you see under subtracting racer-offset="2525252525252525", what it should do, is take the value of 25 + add it to the exisiting value, and that will be the value of racer-offset, till the next scroll takes place.  Thank you

Problem code ------

```
 $('.images').each(function(){
            if($(this).position().left >= $(this).attr('loc')){
            console.log("0 == stopped");

            }
            else {
            speedR = $(this).attr('speed-racer');
            $(this).css({left : "+="+speedR});
            $(this).attr('racer-offset') + speedR;
            $(this).attr('racer-offset', $(this).attr('speed-racer') + $(this).attr('racer-offset'));
            }
        });
```

Entire code:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
if(lastLeftLocation > $(document).scrollLeft()) {
    $('.images').each(function(){
            if($(this).position().left >= $(this).attr('loc')){
            console.log("0 == stopped");

            }
            else {
            speedR = $(this).attr('speed-racer');
            $(this).css({left : "+="+speedR});
            $(this).attr('racer-offset') + speedR;
            $(this).attr('racer-offset', $(this).attr('speed-racer') + $(this).attr('racer-offset'));
            }
        });
    }
else {
    $('.images').each(function(){
        if($(this).attr('racer-offset') <= 0){
        console.log("0 == stopped");
        }
        else {
        speedR = $(this).attr('speed-racer');
        $(this).css({left : "-="+speedR});
        $(this).attr('racer-offset', $(this).attr('racer-offset') - speedR);
        }
    });
}
```

});

HTML

```
   <img class="images" racer-offset="1075" speed-racer="25" src="http://feeneywireless.com/assets/img/fwman/FeeneyMan_prod_st.png" loc="1344" leftmovement="1300" style="left: 1119px;">
```

Subtracting Incorrectly
[image]

Adding correctly
[image]

Comment: `$(this).attr('racer-offset') + speedR;` does nothing. You're adding the two values together but not storing this value at all or using it in any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't converting your values to integers. Therefore your result is a concatenated string:

```
"250" + "250" = "250250";
```

To convert your values to integers, simply stick a [Unary Plus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators) (`+`) before the call:

```
speedR = +$(this).attr('speed-racer');
```

And:

```
$(this).attr('racer-offset',
                   +$(this).attr('speed-racer') + +$(this).attr('racer-offset'));
```

When converted to an integer:

```
250 + 250 = 500;
```

Comment: Yours worked, though I am confused as to the unary plus how that effected the code differently fromw what I had first off.

Comment: The Unary Plus attempts to convert the value to an integer (a number). In JavaScript, when you add two strings together, they are *concatenated*. `"1" + "2" === "12"`. Putting the `+` in front does this conversion for you: `+"1" + +"2" === 3`.
See the bottom of the Unary Plus reference linked in my answer for a more detailed description.

Comment: Flipped a coin to decide who got the correct answer since you and Arun's solution worked. Please +1 Aruns.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing a string concatenation instead of arithmetic addition, convert the string into int using parseInt() before adding them

```
$(this).attr('racer-offset', parseint($(this).attr('speed-racer'), 10) + parseInt($(this).attr('racer-offset'), 10));
```

Comment: @Cam: the `parseInt()` method has two parameters: the value and the base. Here the base is 10 (decimal). You could, for instance, want to output your numbers as binary; for this you'd use base 2, etc...